# Compiled configuration cannot find package

Tags: org-babel, byte-compilation

I am trying to have configuration byte-compiled to improve performances further.

The original code works with no issue. However, adding the optional `compile` argument:

```el
(require 'ob-tangle)
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "dotemacs.org" user-emacs-directory) t)
```

Yields the following:

```
dotemacs.el:79:17:Warning: reference to free variable `package-archives'
dotemacs.el:79:17:Warning: assignment to free variable `package-archives'
dotemacs.el:91:4:Error: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, use-package
```

Here is my [init.el](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/fdd7b798671fcfadb749fa7ba80e9292424a4cc7/init.el#L33-34). And [here is the part that breaks](https://github.com/angrybacon/dotemacs/blob/fdd7b798671fcfadb749fa7ba80e9292424a4cc7/dotemacs.org#6-initialize-melpa) in my `dotemacs.org`.

Comment: You probably need a (package-initialize) before (org-babel-load-file ...)

Comment: Although requiring `use-package` before `org-babel-load-file` did fix my issue. I haven't noticed any improvement in performance. Also, it compiles everytime, even when files didn't change.

Comment: Based on my own experience with keeping configuration in `.org` files, you won't notice any performance gain after byte-compiling your init file because it's insignificant compared to (1) tangling the org-file and (2) loading all the packages. To address the issue (2) use the `:defer t` option of `use-package` where appropriate. To address (1) change your code to check timestamps on the `.org` and the `.el` files and tangle (run `org-babel-load-file`) only when `.org` is newer.

Comment: A little misunderstanding here. When I say performance, I mean runtime performance, not initialization time.